# Python - Proper Inheritance and Folder Structure

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am building a program in Python and would like to follow standards when doing so. I have a module *main.py* which runs the program. *main.py* initiates objects of *A()* located in *program/a.py* and *B()* which is located in *program/b.py*. Both *A* and *B* inherit *Util* from *program/util.py*. The problem is that *Util* also inherits other classes which parse config files. It seems like it would be inefficient for *Util* to be initiated twice. This causes items such as database connections that are handled by *util.py* to be maded twice. What is the most appropriate way to initiate *Util* a single time? The current setup that I have is

In main.py

```
from program.a import A
from program.b import B

class Main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()
        self.b = B()
```

In program/a.py

```
from .util import Util

class A(Util):
    def __init__(self):
        """DO STUFF"""
```

In program/b.py

```
from .util import Util

class B(Util):
    def __init__(self):
        """DO STUFF"""
```

In program/util.py

```
from config import Config
from db import Db  

class Util(Config):
    def __init__(self):
        #Expensive start up items such as establishing database connections
        self.db = Db(self.config)
```

Is this proper or would it be better to pass an object of Util to both A and B when initiating them. For example:

In main.py

```
from program.a import A
from program.b import B
from program.util import Util

class Main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.util = Util()
        self.a = A(self.util)
        self.b = B(self.util)
```

In program/a.py

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(util):
        self.util = util
        """DO STUFF"""
```

In program/b.py

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(util):
        self.util = util
        """DO STUFF"""
```

Additionally, the current folder structure is:

```
/program
    main.py
    /program
        a.py
        b.py
        util.py
        config.py
        db.py
    /config
        config.ini
    /tests
        runtests.py
    /scripts
        script.sh
    /data
        datafile.dat
```

Additionally, is this program structure correct by proper conventions? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to build an egg that gets installed and used. Or are you building an application?

Comment: Just an application. The config files are frequently updated so I don't think that it makes sense to create an egg that would constantly need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to read the chapter from The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Python! on [structuring your project](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/) because it contains a pretty good beginning structure.

Comment: Isn't that for developing an egg, since they are assuming a setup.py file

Comment: Not necessarily, but yes the structure presented there is similar to how you would develop an egg.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a "Standard" per se in Python for doing this. Both solutions appear to be sound to me and neither of them would be wrong, but both have their advantages and disadvantages.

There are a couple of things to consider when you're initializing an object. In general, I try not to do expensive operations on initialization of a class. This allows developers to instantiate the class without actually costing them much. You can do lazy loading of values so that they are only initialized if used.

If the connection is going to be shared and you don't mind slowing down the startup of the application, it may make sense to create an "init" step during startup and then have all your instances simply use the connection from the module. This is not a great solution if the connections you want need to vary based on what each class is doing.

As for project structure I agree with Alex. [The Hitchiker's Guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/) does a good job of telling you how to structure your program. Egg or not.